# If statement to control range of numbers using array

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

I have created an array that holds 5 numbers, and the user inputs the numbers. If the mark is less than 0 and greater than 100, I want to print out "invalid mark number". How could I do that?

```
using namespace std; 

int mark[5];

int main () 
{
cout << "enter mark 0:  ";
cin >> mark[0];


cout << "enter mark 1:  ";
cin >> mark[1];

cout << "enter mark 2:  ";
cin >> mark[2];

cout << "enter mark 3:  ";
cin >> mark[3];

cout << "enter mark 4:  ";
cin >> mark[4];

}
```

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++? No offence but `if` statements should be right near the start.

Comment: Write a function to ask (until valid is given) and return 1 mark. Then call it for each mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`for-loop`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm) to make the code more readable and compact. Because once you introduce [`if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) statements, the code size would grow alot. It should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int mark[5];

int main () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << "enter mark " << i << ":  ";
        cin >> mark[i];
        if (mark[i] < 0 || mark[i] > 100){
            cout << "invalid mark number\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Don't use `using namespace std;` ([read here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) and keep the `int mark[5];` inside the `main`-function ([read here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)). Also to add to the logic force the user to input again:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int mark[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        bool valid_input = false;
        while (!valid_input){
            std::cout << "enter mark " << i << ":  ";
            std::cin >> mark[i];
            if (mark[i] < 0 || mark[i] > 100){
                std::cout << "invalid mark number\n";
            }
            else{
                valid_input = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```